# The "map.getBounds()" result changed after focused input form in leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova, leaflet

I developing a map Android application based on Phonegap with leafletjs and jQueryMobile.
This application has two pages. The 1st page is a Mapview, and 2nd page is preferences consisting of some input forms.

When I focus input form (just only!) in 2nd page and transit to 1st page,  map bounds changed for some reason.

EG.
Before change. The southWest is distinct form northEast.

```
L.map.getBounds().toBBoxString();  // 135.42702913284302,34.68926290260606,135.42702913284302,34.68926290260606
```

After focused input form. The southWest is identical with northEast!

```
L.map.getBounds().toBBoxString();  // 135.42702913284302,34.68926290260606,135.4544949531555,34.70252981597828
```

Anyone else have the same problem?
I could not find a method to set bounds for map.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I assume happens:

1. you focus the input field
2. the styling on the input field somehow triggers the window.resize event
3. the leaflet map size is invalidated
4. when you request the bounds it reads the new size (since the old one is invalidated) which is zero since the map is hidden -- presumably

That is because `getBounds` calls:

```
getPixelBounds: function () {
    var topLeftPoint = this._getTopLeftPoint();
    return new L.Bounds(topLeftPoint, topLeftPoint.add(this.getSize()));
},
```

the `topLeftPoint` is intact, but size is [0,0] and you get NE = SW.

Possible solutions:

A. cache the bounds before transitioning to the second page
B. investigate why the input focus triggers a window resize